maven-shade-plugin when dealing with classifiers AND no classifiers
I have a pom that builds and installs a jar and is configured with a classifier:
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
   </configuration
</plugin>

I have 1 profile that sets ${classifier} to empty and builds the artifact with no classifier and another that sets ${classifier} to my desired classifier and builds the artifact with a classifier, such that the following artifacts can be built:
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar

I'm trying to implement the maven-shade-plugin so that each Uber jar and original jar has their respective classifier, like this:
original-artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
original-artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar

Firstly, the shade plugin fails when the maven-jar-plugin uses a classifier. According to another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775031/20291988), the shade-plugin expects a non-classified artifact. Fine, so I figured I can remove the classifier from maven-jar-plugin and add it to the maven-shade-plugin. In order to add the classifier to my artifact, I add the following configuration to my shade plugin execution:
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
<shadedClassifierName>${classifier}</shadedClassifierName>

Now, when I build the classifier profile, I get the following:
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar              <-- original classified jar
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classifier.jar   <-- Uber classified jar

and when I build the non-classified profile, I get the following:
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar              <-- original non-classified jar
artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar       <-- Uber non-classified jar

Even if I rename the artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar to artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, the problem is that the original classified jar overwrites it when being installed.
Is there a better way to use the maven-shade-plugin to build and install artifacts such that the names are consistent whether or not the artifact has a classifier? It feels like this wouldn't be an issue if the main artifact (via the jar plugin) that the shade plugin expects could have a classifier. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve adding a different classifier to my non-classified artifact.
